# How to add twitter4j to add to Android project (in eclipse)?

Tags: android, eclipse, twitter, twitter4j

I am trying to use [twitter4j as library from github](https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/) in my android project. I dont see the jar files anywhere to add to the 'libs' folder of my project.

How else to add [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html) for use in my android app?

Comment: Download from http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html. you downlaoded the source. Download `twitter4j-3.0.5.zip`

Comment: You can follow http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_twitter_integration.htm

Comment: Thanks - you are right. I found the JAR files on the website, github has source only

Answer (score 0):

To add a reference to a library project, follow these steps:

1) Make sure that both the project library and the application project that depends on it are in your workspace. If one of the projects is missing, import it into your workspace.

2) In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.

3) In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.

4) Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.

5) From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.

6) When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.

7)Click OK to close the Properties window.

refer [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject)

Comment: thanks, I knew how to add projects / jar files as libraries, problem was i was not looking for the twitter4j jar file at the right place.